# How get a variable of scope in an attribute different than ng-*

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I use a this datePicker : http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ with AngularJS, like this :

```
<div class='col-md-2'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>End date</label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='endDate' data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD">
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In real world the date format is set in $socpe.dateFormat in my controller, but I don't know how to bind a $scope.dateFormat in the attribute data-date-format.

Comment: I think you just need to put it in double curly braces. {{dateFormat}}

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used [angular-ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) datepicker instead of [bootstrap-datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), it works very fine with less code.

Thank you @theJoeBiz for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to combine angularjs with a jquery plugin. You *could* create a custom directive to wrap it, but why not use something already meant for angular? A couple choices would be [angular-ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepickers).

Comment: You are right, if we mix 2 frameworks, it will be hard to maintain. I migrated all my jquery code to native angularjs.